# Use apollo stack with meteor

Tags: meteor, apollo

i'm trying to use apollp stack with my meteor project. i used

```
meteor add apollo
meteor npm install --save apollo-client apollo-server express
```

to install apollo stack but when i execute meteor to run my project it gives errors

```
/home/xxxxxx/Example/crud/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/modules.js:97872
const graphql_1 = require('graphql');
^^^^^   
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
at/home/xxxxxx/Example/crud/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:292:30
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/xxxxxxx/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.4_1.1wjluqr++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
```

Any ideas about what happened here ??

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to do the same thing. I think I can get you to the next step. Just add a couple of things to your npm install:

`meteor npm install --save apollo-client apollo-server@^0.1.1 express graphql`

I've put in a PR to add graphql to the npm install in the docs. Also, apollo-server has recently updated to 0.2, but meteor-integration is [still working on it](https://github.com/apollostack/meteor-integration/pull/26) - the `@^0.1.1` will not be needed when this is resolved. I'm still having some issues, so this may not get you all the way there, but it resolved this error for me.

Comment: Off-topic, but I am curious how Express works with Meteor?  I never thought about using it on Meteor.  It doesn't interfere at all w/ things like DDP?

Comment: Meteor includes an http server that uses npm connect for middleware. [Here's how it's done with Apollo](https://github.com/apollostack/meteor-integration/blob/master/main-server.js). It can function side-by-side with DDP no problem. MDG has announced that Meteor 1.5 will have Apollo integration, so we'll see more on this front soon. One advantage will be the ability to move some queries off of DDP to enhance scalability when reactivity is not essential.